# Grammar in "prevent Saudi help"

Tags: adjectives

From [tribune.com](http://tribune.com.pk/story/1004949/saudi-must-stop-financing-fundamentalist-mosques-abroad-merkels-deputy/):

> We will prevent Saudi help in the building or financing of mosques in Germany where Wahhabi ideas are to be disseminated,” he told the Welt am Sonntag newspaper.

I know we can use noun as adjective whenever we want, for example "boy-style", so is "Saudi" an adjective describing "help" here? But this is a bit strange to me, is this common or normal?

Or is it a typo of "prevent Saudi helping in the building" or "prevent Saudi's help in the building"?

Comment: No, it modifies the elided noun "Arabia" or "Arabian."

Comment: @CodeGnome It is not really an elision of "Arabian". **By itself**, "Saudi" is synonymous with "Saudi Arabian".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,

**Saudi** is an adjective:

> adjective
>   [of or relating to Saudi Arabia or its inhabitants](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/saudi)

--Collins Dictionary. See also [18 other dictionary results](http://www.onelook.com/?w=Saudi&ls=a).

The definition and example sentences in [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/saudi?q=Saudi) should suffice to show that its usage is common and normal:

> adjective
>   Relating to Saudi Arabia or its ruling dynasty.
>
> Example sentences
>   *Until 1964, Saudi girls were not allowed to go to school.*
>
> *According to the movie, these Saudi investors own about 7 percent of the U.S. economy.*
>
> *As a new rule, all Saudi visitors to the US are interviewed, fingerprinted and photographed upon arrival.*

It is also a noun.

Comment: "Saudi" is both a noun and an adjective. Your answer really doesn't help the OP understand its use in the sentence, though.

Comment: Oh really @CodeGnome, can you read the OP's mind?

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not it's strictly grammatical, a lot of Americans hear "Saudi" as an adjective that modifies "Arabia" or "Arabian." As a result, it's fairly common to elide the noun, even in semi-formal speech such as newscasts.

There are certainly other ways to look at this particular sentence construct, but as a native speaker I would recommend hearing it as:

> We will prevent Saudi (Arabian) help...

rather than trying to apply more complex grammatical rules.